# deadlock detected during oracle expdp

Tags: oracle, deadlock, export

I have an Oracle 11g and I wanted to export all my shcema objects,

with this command:

```
expdp as '/ as sysdba' directory=DIR dumpfile=DWH%U.dmp logfile=DWH.log filesize=40000m parallel=32 schemas=DWH
```

This is the start of the output I'v got:

```
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 1840. GB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLESPACE_QUOTA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYNONYM/SYNONYM
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TYPE/TYPE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DB_LINK
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/SEQUENCE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SEQUENCE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
ORA-39014: One or more workers have prematurely exited.
ORA-39029: worker 14 with process name "DW0D" prematurely terminated
ORA-31671: Worker process DW0D had an unhandled exception.
ORA-39078: unable to dequeue message for agent KUPC$A_1_100742920000000 from queue "KUPC$C_1_20190915100610"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPC$QUE_INT", line 610
ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object SYS.KUPC$C_1_20190915100610
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 1887
ORA-06512: at line 2
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/AUDIT_OBJ
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/RLS_POLICY/RLS_POLICY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/COMPILE_PACKAGE/PACKAGE_SPEC/ALTER_PACKAGE_SPEC
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/FUNCTION/ALTER_FUNCTION
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/VIEW/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PACKAGE/PACKAGE_BODY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TYPE/TYPE_BODY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYNONYM/RLS_POLICY/RLS_POLICY
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/REF_CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/BITMAP_INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/BITMAP_INDEX/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TRIGGER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/MATERIALIZED_VIEW
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/JOB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/REFRESH_GROUP
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/POST_SCHEMA/PROCOBJ
. . exported "DWH"."T3"                            9.119 GB 21698829
```

The exception occured but the export hasn't failed.. and I can see that the tables start to be exported.

What is this exception mean? deadlock on object of sys?
I can see that the object "KUPC$C_1_20190915100610" is a queue of SYS..
Should I need to restart my export or can I use it after finished?

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that the doc for expdp _begins_ with this hightlighted notice: "Do not start Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users."   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-D5455260-C28C-475F-9E0E-2BE227E7F0E3.htm#SUTIL824

Answer (score -1):

since you have multiple errors I recommend you to do the following:

1. if you have an old dump inside this directory move it to another place.
2. execute the following command `select * from v$sgastat where pool='streams pool';` and increase `STREAMS_POOL_SIZE` value.
3. check `open_cursor` value and increase it (make sure `scope=both` when you edit it).

Note: I would recommend leaving step 3 to the end. Try to take a backup before executing it.